# How Django rest IsAdminUser does not pass even the user is admin?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    django_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='admin')
```

```
class AdminAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Admin.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdminSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Admin.objects.filter(username=self.request.user.admin.username)
        else:
            return []

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = AdminSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            email = serializer.data['email']
            username = serializer.data['email']
            password = serializer.data['password']

            with transaction.atomic():
                django_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
              
                admin = Admin.objects.create(**serializer.data, django_user=django_user)
                #User.objects.filter(pk=1001).update(is_superuser=True, is_staff=True)

                return Response(admin.pk)

        return Response('/error')


class ClientFullAccessAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            email = serializer.data['email']
            username = serializer.data['email']
            password = serializer.data['password']

            with transaction.atomic():
                django_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                client = Client.objects.create(**serializer.data, django_user=django_user)
                return Response(client.username)

        return Response('/error')
```

`Here am trying to make the admin see the all the clients and the client see his data only ,... but I couldn't find why the i cant see the all the list clients as an admin,  I am keep getting not authorized to access this endpoint..

`

## urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

import user_management.views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients', user_management.views.ClientReadOnlyAPIViewSet)
router.register(r'clientslist', user_management.views.ClientFullAccessAPIViewSet)
router.register(r'admin', user_management.views.AdminAPIViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    #path('clients/', user_management.views.ClientAPIViewSet.as_view(), name="clients"),
]
```

[image]

`Here am trying to make the admin see the all the clients and the client see his data only ,... but I couldn't find why the i cant see the all the list clients as an admin,  I am keep getting not authorized to access this endpoint..any help please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defined your `Admin` model from a regular Django model so Django cannot find the user permissions associated to it.

You should inherit from a Django authentication user model (`AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`) as indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project).

For instance, you can do:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomAdminUser(AbstractUser):
    # Here you normally only want to 
    # define the fields not defined in 
    # the base model AbstractUser
    pass
```

Then, to create your admin:

```py
CustomAdminUser.objects.create_superuser(...)
```

Last but not least, two important things (mentioned in the above Django documentation's link):

- Don’t forget to point the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to your custom user model. Do this before creating any migrations or running `manage.py migrate` for the first time.
- Register the model in the app’s `admin.py`.